# How can we integrate facebook analytics in hybrid app

Tags: ionic-framework

.controller('Facebook',function($scope,$timeout,$log)
{

ionic.Platform.ready(function () {

facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit('162745127525160');

})

```
  var self = this;
  $timeout(function () {

            facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit('162745127525160');
            facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
             $log.info(response);
             if (response.status === 'connected') {
              $log.info('User Already LoggedIn');
               self.getData();
               } else {
                   $log.info('User Not Logged In');
               }
            }, function () {
               $log.warn('Get Login Status Error');

            });
            }, 1000);
          $scope.facebookLogin = function () {
          facebookConnectPlugin.login(['public_profile'], function (data) {
             $log.info(data);
             self.getData();
          }, function (data) {
             $log.warn(data);
          });
          };
          self.getData = function () {
          facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me', ['public_profile'], function (data) {
             $log.info(data);
             $scope.$apply(function () {
                 $scope.fb_data = data;
             });
          });
          };
```

})

I have already install plugin to integrate Facebook .

Error
ReferenceError: FacebookConnectPlugin is not defined
 Uncaught Reference Error: FacebookConnectPlugin is not defined

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) What is your question? Please look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Sir i just want to know how can i integrate Facebook analytics app events in ionic

Comment: Try to express yourself a bit better. Stackoverflow is not a coding service, you have to try to solve your problem and ask for help. There are tutorials, search them in google.com.

Comment: @Mark : Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cordova plugin managing the Facebook SDK integration. Here's the link to the related Github project:

https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

Check the description in there and follow it step by step, as it's also necessary to correctly set up your app in your Facebook developer account and to pass the ID to the plugin when installing to start tracking. ;)

Comment: Thanks u sir for ur help . I install this plugin in my project but whenever i tried to use this plugin it give me error . "facebookConnectPlugin is not defined"

Comment: Have you ensured that you wrap your first call to the Facebook plugin in `ionic.Platform.ready(function(){ facebookConnectPlugin.[...] })`? This ensures that the plugin is initialized correctly.

Comment: Yes sir  

 ionic.Platform.ready(function () {
          if (window.cordova.platformId == "browser") {
          facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit('APP ID');
       }
    })

Comment: Sir in this plugin i didnt find any file under the name facebookConnectPlugin